# SharePoint Framework - Create a lookup column using feature

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, feature-activation, addfieldasxml

My requirement is to create a Custom List using the Feature (SPFx solution). I have created a custom list using the SPFx feature, I have created a different type of field. But now I want to create a **Lookup column** using this feature, But I'm not able to create a Lookup column.

I have tried, List="Lists/City" and also tried "List="City" but it is not working. Other fields are created but the Lookup column is not created. If I provided a list GUID then also I'm not able to create a Lookup column.

following is my xml schema to create a Lookup column.

```
     <Field ID="{95d89725-eb97-428b-bc79-ee02ca8b724c}"
         Name="City"
         SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"
         StaticName="City"
         Type="Lookup"
         DisplayName="City"
         List="City"
         FieldRef="ID"
         ShowField="Title"
    />
```

Tell me how I can create the Lookup column using the SPFx feature with XML schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create a lookup column using this CAML:

```
<Field 
    ID="{3578a673-d4db-4f2e-b721-2c68eb994588}" 
    Name="SpfxCity" 
    DisplayName="City" 
    Type="Lookup" 
    List="Lists/City" 
    ShowField="Title"
    Group="SPFx Columns" />
```

Here's the complete `elements.xml` file that I used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

    <Field 
        ID="{3578a673-d4db-4f2e-b721-2c68eb994588}" 
        Name="SpfxCity" 
        DisplayName="City" 
        Type="Lookup" 
        List="Lists/City" 
        ShowField="Title"
        Group="SPFx Columns" />

    <ContentType ID="0x01008A91C228836E480F987C78C60518A422"
            Name="SPFx Content Type"
            Group="SPFx Content Types"
            Description="Sample content types from web part solution">
        <FieldRefs>
            <FieldRef ID="{3578a673-d4db-4f2e-b721-2c68eb994588}" />
        </FieldRefs>
    </ContentType>

    <ListInstance
            CustomSchema="schema.xml"
            FeatureId="00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100"
            Title="SPFx List"
            Description="SPFx List"
            TemplateType="100"
            Url="Lists/SPFxList">
    </ListInstance>

</Elements>
```

Here's the complete `schema.xml` that I used.

```
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="SPFx List" EnableContentTypes="TRUE" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/SPFxList" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentTypeRef ID="0x01008A91C228836E480F987C78C60518A422" />
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields></Fields>
    <Views>
      <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="SpfxCity"></FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="ID" />
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
      </View>
    </Views>
    <Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
    </Forms>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

I tried to follow the example shown in this tutorial as much as possible: [Provision SharePoint assets from your SharePoint client-side web part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/provision-sp-assets-from-package?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-9698). Please note that there appears to be a step missing in this tutorial. You need to ensure that the `skipFeatureDeployment` property in `package-solution.json` is set to `false`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Rob Windsor. Yes. this way created. I have not created List Columns and Content Type. I was trying to create a List Column. But this way also worked for me

Comment: I have 1 problem here, I'm creating a Lookup list in the Same Feature. I'm able to create a Lookup Column but I'm not able to see it in the List. It was also added to the Content-Type but not shown in the List. 

Can you @Rob Windsor tell me why?